# Problems with combining columns from dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I'm trying to merge.

```
               df1
    code  scale   R1    R2...
0   121     1     80    110
1   121     2     NaN   NaN
2   121     3     NaN   NaN
3   313     1     60    60
4   313     2     NaN   NaN
5   313     3     NaN   NaN
...
             df2
    code  scale   R1    R2...
0   121     2     30    20
3   313     2     15    10
...
```

I need, based on the equality of the columns `code` and `scale` copy the value from `df2` to `df1`.

The result should look like this:

```
               df1
    code  scale   R1    R2...
0   121     1     80    110
1   121     2     30    20
2   121     3     NaN   NaN
3   313     1     60    60
4   313     2     15    10
5   313     3     NaN   NaN
...
```

The problem is that there can be a lot of columns like `R1` and `R2` and I can not check each one separately, so I wanted to use something [from this instruction](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), but nothing gives me the desired result. I'm doing something wrong, but I can't understand what. I really need advice.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the two dataframes both have values for R1/R2? If you want keep df1 you could do `df1.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()`

Comment: @KenSyme why don't you make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want to happen if the two dataframes both have values for R1/R2? If you want keep df1, you could do

```
df1.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
```

To keep df2 just do the fillna the other way round. To combine in some other way please clarify the question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention that the values in `df1`, except for the line where the `scale`  is `1` will always be empty. in fact, I want to fill it with data from `df2` and other dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ?

```
pd.concat([df,df1],axis=0).sort_values(['code','scale']).drop_duplicates(['code','scale'],keep='last')    
Out[21]: 
    code  scale    R1     R2
0   121      1  80.0  110.0
0   121      2  30.0   20.0
2   121      3   NaN    NaN
3   313      1  60.0   60.0
3   313      2  15.0   10.0
5   313      3   NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good situation for `combine_first`. It replaces the nulls in the calling dataframe from the passed dataframe.

```
df1.set_index(['code', 'scale']).combine_first(df2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()

   code  scale    R1     R2
0   121      1  80.0  110.0
1   121      2  30.0   20.0
2   121      3   NaN    NaN
3   313      1  60.0   60.0
4   313      2  15.0   10.0
5   313      3   NaN    NaN
```

Other solutions

*`with fillna`*

```
df.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df1.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
```

*`with add`* - a bit faster

```
df.set_index(['code', 'scale']).add(df1.set_index(['code', 'scale']), fill_value=0)
```